# HQL: Division inside Criteria Query

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql, criteria

This doesn't work in Hibernate, because sum seems to be only able to take in one property:
                            `criteria.setProjection(Projections.sum("h.dogs/h.cats"));`

How do I rewrite this, without using any native SQL, as a criteria Projection or the like? If I just put h.dogs inside the sum, then that works but I need to divide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good solution.

```
@Formula("dogs / cats")
private double calculation;
```

in my Object class did the trick, I can then refer to it via

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.sum("h.calculation"));
```